# I have created a new core in solr and once I restart my tomcat server the core gets deleted.why does the core in solr gets deleted?

Tags: solr

I am using apache solr and I have created another core and its works fine.But once i shutdown my server and restart it,the new core gets deleted. But the folder seems to be there in the solr dir.Can any one tell me why does it get deleted from my apache solr? Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you create the new core ?? through Admin urls ?

Comment: I created a new core,by clicking on Add core on the core admin page in apache solr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for the [persistent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#CREATE) attribute in the solr.xml `<solr persistent="true">` which will persist the changes made through Admin UI and these would be available after restarts as well.

> If persistence is enabled (persist=true), the configuration for this
>   new core will be saved in 'solr.xml'.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra.. Where I can get this file. I mean at what location.

Comment: The persist=true property is not longer valid for solr 5