# How do I stop Solr cores being deleted by Tomcat restart

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene, tomcat7, solr4

I am running Solr-4.10.1 on Tomcat-7. I have placed the necessary `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` in `/usr/share/solr/data/test/conf`, and created a new core using:

```
curl --request POST 'xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/solr/admin/cores' --data "action=CREATE&name=test&instanceDir=/usr/share/solr/data/test&config=solrconfig.xml&schema=schema.xml&dataDir=/usr/share/solr/data/test"
```

from the command line. I can then write to and read from the core, but when I restart Tomcat the core disappears.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647067/i-have-created-a-new-core-in-solr-and-once-i-restart-my-tomcat-server-the-core-g) that putting `persist=true` into `solr.xml` fixes the issue, however I have also read that this is soon to be deprecated [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml):

> The persistent attribute is no longer supported in solr.xml

Does anybody know how to persist cores for the newest versions of Solr?

#### Edit:

Here are the contents of my `solr.xml` located at `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml`.

```
<Context docBase="/usr/share/solr/example/multicore/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr/example/multicore" override="true" />
</Context>
```

Comment: What style solr.xml are you using? The one that does core auto-discovery or the old-style one that lists every core?

Comment: I have added the contents of my `solr.xml` to the post. Note that these are the defaults as created during the installation steps followed from http://webikon.com/cases/installing-apache-solr-4-7-multicore-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-tomcat7

Comment: That's not the right solr.xml. That's the tomcat definition to find solr's webapp. You should have another one in your solr home: /usr/share/solr/example/multicore in your case.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks very much for the help. Based on your help I've posted what is now the answer should others come across this issue with the new-style config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

The default `solr.xml` for Tomcat indicated that Solr was using `/usr/share/solr/example/multicore` as the data directory, not where I had put my new cores. I changed `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml` to point at my new data directory at `/usr/share/solr/data`:*

```
<Context docBase="/usr/share/solr/example/multicore/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr/data" override="true" />
</Context>
```

In my new data directory I created a new `solr.xml` with the following contents, which I copied from the example provided with the installation at `/usr/share/solr/example/solr/solr.xml` (comments trimmed here). It is all default boilerplate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr>

  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:0}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:0}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

This is the new-style `solr.xml`, and so core discovery is on. See [this link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Core%20Discovery%20%284.4%20and%20beyond%29) for more information.

Finally, I put an empty `core.properties` in the root of each core that I wanted to be discovered on reboot, e.g. at `/usr/share/solr/data/mycore/core.properties`. Cores now persist through Tomcat restarts.

Many thanks to @alexandre-rafalovitch for his help and pointing me in the right direction - see comments below the question.

*: A note for the observant: I have left `solr.war` in its original place as it is unrelated to the matter at hand.

Answer (score 0):

My solr Application is running on jetty. I tried everything but nothing was working. Then I realized my application was created under "multicore" section. Tehn I tried 2 things:
a. I modified my solr.xml (\example\multicore) as:

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
```

b.I restarted my start.jar with

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=multicore -jar start.jar
```

and it worked. Hope it helps.